# need to hide Unchecked boxes when Printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, ms-word

My boss needs either an html document or a word document.  That when he goes to print the document it will only show the boxes that he has checked.  There is a huge list of check boxes so he does not want to print the entire thing every time.  Just the ones that matter for a particular client.

I have tried several methods of javascript, and css hidden neither of which have worked.  Have also tried playing with the developers macros in microsoft word.  None of those have given me what I am needing.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
 <p>
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="checkbox" id="box" />
  Main.</label>
<br />
 <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1"       id="boxchecked" />
  Other.</label>
<br />
</p>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boxchecked").click(function (){
        if ($("#boxchecked").prop("checked")){
            $("#hidden").hide();
        }else{
            $("#hidden").show();
        }              
    });
});
</script>



' Determine if there are any items checked.
If checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then
   ' If so, loop through all checked items and print results.
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim s As String = ""
   For x = 0 To checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
      s = s & "Checked Item " & (x + 1).ToString & " = " & CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(x).ToString & ControlChars.CrLf
   Next x
   MessageBox.Show (s)
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your script seems to be trying to hide or show some element with the id `hidden`, which I don't see in your HTML anywhere.

But regardless there's a much easier way to do this with CSS.

```
@media print {
  input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok this code works. 

           @media print { input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) { display: none; } } 
However I can not find how to hide the label with the unchecked boxes for print. I have tried adding + label in several places and neither way works any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like the media query below but you want to make sure the browser being used is compatible.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp

```
@media print { 
#boxchecked:not(:checked){ display: none; }
}
```

or in the case of a page with many checkbox elements you can create a css class and have the media query apply to all of them:

```
@media print { 
.cbx:not(:checked){ display: none; }
}
```

Hope that helps! :)